# table not dropped properly

Tags: sql, oracle

a table was not properly dropped down- as a result the constraint on the table still exists, can you please suggest how to disable/drop a constraint on the non existing table.

I tried with cascade but ended up with error- table does not exist.

Comment: Wierd case as iam pretty sure Oracle database requires you to add `CASCADE CONSTRAINTS` to the `DROP TABLE` statement if the table has constraints otherwise it will not drop the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the constraints with

```
SELECT owner, table_name, constraint_type, status FROM user_constraints
```

The constraint type is one of

- **C**    Check on a table    Column
- **O**    Read Only on a view     Object
- **P**    Primary Key
- **R**    Referential AKA Foreign Key
- **U**    Unique Key
- **V**    Check Option on a view

See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Oracle_Database/SQL_Cheatsheet#Constraint_types_and_codes

I assume that there are foreign key constraints (type 'R') on other tables that point to the table you want to delete.
You can either **drop** the affected constraints, or **disable** them temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach that using SQL

```sql
--Drop a Constraint 
if exists (select * from sysobjects where xtype = 'f' and name = 'Constraint Name')
    alter table "Table Name"
      Drop constraint "Constraint Name"   
go
```

Hope this helps.